# Apache Camel File-Watch Without Spring

Tags: java, apache-camel, file-watcher

I am trying to use Apache Camel File-Watch feature.

However I notice all example are used along with Spring.

Is there anyway to make use of this feature without Spring ?

Thank you for any potential input.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Apache Camel* is a standalone integration framework to easily integrate different systems using well know and established EIP (Enterprise Integration Patterns).

It is not tied to *Spring* in any way at its core and has different deployment / integration models out of which is *Spring* / *Spring Boot* for the sake of easing its adoption and configuration for *Spring* framework users.

Out of the runtime contexts, you can use for example [*Camel Main* component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/others/main.html) to run your application having a [*File Watch* component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.17.x/file-watch-component.html) setup to watch the `/tmp/` directory change events:

The main application would look like the following:

```
public class FileWatchApplication {

    private FileWatchApplication() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // use Camels Main class
        Main main = new Main(FileWatchApplication.class);
        // now keep the application running until the JVM is terminated (ctrl + c or sigterm)
        main.run(args);
    }
}
```

A simple `RouteBuilder` setting up your *File Watch* component would look like the following (note that it **must be within the same (or child) package of the `FileWatchApplication` class**):

```
public class FileWatchRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // snippet configuration from the official documentation
        from("file-watch:///tmp/")
                .log("File event: ${header.CamelFileEventType} occurred on file ${header.CamelFileName} at ${header.CamelFileLastModified}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @tmarwen, thank you for your input. I realized its the Camel Main that I should be using. Grateful to you for your input. Regards.

Comment: Glad to be in help! Happy Camel riding :)

Answer (score -2):

Camel is based on Spring.  In fact, the Camel Context is an extension of the Spring Application Context.  So if you have Camel, you also must have Spring.

Comment: No it's not - this is plain wrong. One can use Camel with Spring thought.